# Using XPATH/XQUERY to select all values for elements with attribute X

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery

I am relatively new to XPath and XQuery. I am working with XML stored in a table called `tblXML`. 
XML is stored in this table by `caseID`. For this example, this value is unique.
The XML itself is stored in a column labeled `Data`.

If you were to `select * from tblXML where caseID = '12345'` you would see this:

```
caseID        data
------        ------
12345         <root><patient><diagnosis preferred_name="diagnosis" tier="1">Melanoma</diagnosis> (XML file stored as blob in database)
```

If you were to dive into the XML, it would look something like this. For example, this is the XML in the `data` column for `caseID` '12345':

```
<root>
    <patient>
        <diagnosis preferred_name="diagnosis" tier="1">Melanoma</diagnosis>
        <month_of_birth preferred_name="month_of_birth" tier="1">02</month_of_birth>
        <day_of_birth preferred_name="day_of_birth" tier="2">01</day_of_birth>
        <year_of_birth preferred_name="year_of_birth" tier="1">1960</year_of_birth>
        <new_tumor_events>
            <month_of_nte preferred_name="month_of_nte" tier="1">12</month_of_nte>
            <day_of_nte preferred_name="day_of_nte" tier="2">30</day_of_nte>
            <year_of_nte preferred_name="year_of_nte" tier="1">1994</year_of_nte>
        </new_tumor_events>
        <follow_ups>
            <follow_up>
                <month_of_fu preferred_name="month_of_fu" tier="1">12</month_of_fu>
                <day_of_fu preferred_name="day_of_fu" tier="2">31</day_of_fu>
                <year_of_fu preferred_name="year_of_fu" tier="1">1995</year_of_fu>
            </follow_up>
            <follow_up>
                <month_of_fu preferred_name="month_of_fu" tier="1">12</month_of_fu>
                <day_of_fu preferred_name="day_of_fu" tier="2">31</day_of_fu>
                <year_of_fu preferred_name="year_of_fu" tier="1">1996</year_of_fu>
            </follow_up>
        </follow_ups>
    </patient>
</root>
```

**Goals:**
I am trying to select all values for all elements at all levels/nodes of the XML document that have a `@Tier` attribute of `"1"`. I would like to see each value be output in it's own row in a column called 'Value' like this:

```
caseID     Value
------     ------
12345      Melanoma
12345      02
12345      1960
12345      12
12345      1994
12345      12
12345      1995
12345      12
12345      1996
```

Here's SQL that's analogous to what I'm trying to write:

```
DECLARE @tier int 
SET @tier = '1' --To search by tier explicitly via variable

    select 
        x.caseID,
    bar.value('(//*[@tier = sql:variable("@tier")])[1]','varchar(max)') as value
from tblXML as x
    CROSS APPLY data.nodes('//*:patient') AS foo(bar)
where
    x.caseID = '12345'
    and x.data.value('(//@tier)[1]', 'varchar(3)') = '1'
```

This gives me...

```
case ID        value
------         ------  
12345          Melanoma
```

...but not the additional rows I'm looking for.

I think the my confusion centers around both the constraint imposed by the singleton `[1]` and the context node in my CROSS APPLY statement. I'm not sure how to get everything in the document that's Tier 1, not just the first instance of Tier 1 that the query finds.

For this example I know my context node in my CROSS APPLY statement is focused on the `patient` section of the XML, but I  would like to be able to search at all levels of the XML tree both up and down. I know the `//` for `@Tier` lets me search at all levels of the document, but my context node seems to drive/constrain me to some degree on how deep into the document I can search.

It's my understanding that I can drill deep into the XML (`follow_up` perhaps?), then search from the top down. However, the deepest node will change from caseID to caseID and XML document to XML document. Is there a way to wildcard my CROSS APPLY statement into the deepest node in a given XML document and then look for any occurrence of `@Tier` within that document, then retrieve its corresponding value?

I realize that method lacks elegance and is not performant. I have not been able to find clear documentation thus far to give me the results I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I should specify that this SQL will be the core of a table-valued function in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Define a key:

```
<xsl:key name="t" match="*[@tier]" use="@tier"/>
```

and find all the teir=1 elements using

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('t', '1')">
  ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the singleton in your select:

```
DECLARE @tier int 
SET @tier = '1' --To search by tier explicitly via variable
    select 
        x.caseID,
        bar.value('/string()','varchar(max)')
from tblXML as x
    CROSS APPLY data.nodes('//*[@tier = sql:variable("@tier")]') AS foo(bar)
where
    x.caseID = '12345'
```

The xpath in your select already filters nodes based on the matching attribute value, so you don't need to do it again in your where constraint. The xpath predicate is analogous to where.

Comment: I'm sorry, this seems helpful but I'm unsure how I would weave this into my current SQL statement. Could you please illustrate?

Comment: @Mister_Moto I don't follow what you're doing in SQL. It's not clear what you want the final output to be, or how your XML is associated with `caseID`. I'd recommend updating your question to include all relevant data, along with expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I've gone back and edited the original question to try and add more clarity.

Comment: @Mister_Moto Take a look at this updated example. I haven't tested this, so there may be syntax issues, but I think the idea is there (you were overthinking it ;).

Comment: I just tried it, and got this error message:

`XQuery [dbo.tblXML.data.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'`

Given that I'm running SQL Server 2005 (we're in dire need of an upgrade) I think that we're outpacing the Xpath/XQuery standards >.<

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mister_Moto If I understand the error correctly, this is now a SQL question more than XPath. I think the problem was the select was choosing a singleton and a sequence and failing on the sequence. I moved the sequence to the `CROSS APPLY`, and that should correct that fundamental problem. My SQL is really rusty, so you may need to repost this as a SQL question. However the XPath is right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    x.caseID,
    bar.value('.','varchar(max)') as value
FROM tblXML as x
    CROSS APPLY data.nodes('//*[@tier=1]') AS foo(bar)
```

Comment: Why should they? Provide a bit of explanation as to why this code works.  This will discourage copying and pasting without understanding the design choices you have made.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do the tier lookup from the CROSS APPLY statement, and take value of the root in your select ('.' as first argument).

```sql
DECLARE @s XML;
SET @s='<root>
    <patient>
        <diagnosis preferred_name="diagnosis" tier="1">Melanoma</diagnosis>
        <month_of_birth preferred_name="month_of_birth" tier="1">02</month_of_birth>
        <day_of_birth preferred_name="day_of_birth" tier="2">01</day_of_birth>
        <year_of_birth preferred_name="year_of_birth" tier="1">1960</year_of_birth>
        <new_tumor_events>
            <month_of_nte preferred_name="month_of_nte" tier="1">12</month_of_nte>
            <day_of_nte preferred_name="day_of_nte" tier="2">30</day_of_nte>
            <year_of_nte preferred_name="year_of_nte" tier="1">1994</year_of_nte>
        </new_tumor_events>
        <follow_ups>
            <follow_up>
                <month_of_fu preferred_name="month_of_fu" tier="1">12</month_of_fu>
                <day_of_fu preferred_name="day_of_fu" tier="2">31</day_of_fu>
                <year_of_fu preferred_name="year_of_fu" tier="1">1995</year_of_fu>
            </follow_up>
            <follow_up>
                <month_of_fu preferred_name="month_of_fu" tier="1">12</month_of_fu>
                <day_of_fu preferred_name="day_of_fu" tier="2">31</day_of_fu>
                <year_of_fu preferred_name="year_of_fu" tier="1">1996</year_of_fu>
            </follow_up>
        </follow_ups>
    </patient>
</root>';

DECLARE @tblXML TABLE(caseID INT PRIMARY KEY,data XML);
INSERT INTO @tblXML(caseID,data)VALUES(12345,@s);

DECLARE @tier INT;
SET @tier=1;

SELECT
    t.caseID,
    node.value('.','NVARCHAR(512)') AS value
FROM
    @tblXML AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.data.nodes('//*[@tier=sql:variable("@tier")]') AS t1n(node)
WHERE
    t.caseID=12345;
```